# emacs zoom in/zoom out

Tags: emacs

Is there a way to zoom in and out (dynamically change the font size, quite smoothly) on emacs?

Comment: Also works on emacs 24

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Try <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-+</kbd> and <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C--</kbd>; that is, <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Minus</kbd>/<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Plus</kbd>.

After one combination (<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-+</kbd> or <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C--</kbd>), successives <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> increase or decrease the text scale without typing <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-</kbd> again.

**Addition by sawa**

I looked up the function that was assigned to the keys mentioned, and found out that they are `text-scale-increase` and `text-scale-decrease`. I added the following to my configuration file so that I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll</kbd> to zoom in/out. It is useful.

```lisp
(global-set-key [C-mouse-4] 'text-scale-increase)
(global-set-key [C-mouse-5] 'text-scale-decrease)
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I will try to assign that to scroll wheel (maybe with Ctrl) on the mouse.

Comment: You can also call `(text-scale-set LEVEL)` if you know in advance what you want. For instance, I use this to reduce the font size in ibuffer by default: `(add-hook 'ibuffer-mode-hook 'my-ibuffer-mode-hook) (defun my-ibuffer-mode-hook () (text-scale-set -1))`

Comment: For smoothly zooming in and out, I can use the functions that nvm let me know. For having different display modes, phils function maybe good.

Comment: Somehow Sawa's wheel up/down command doesn't work for me, but this one does: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-<wheel-up>") 'text-scale-increase)`
`(global-set-key (kbd "C-<wheel-down>") 'text-scale-decrease)`

Comment: It seems that the `minus` must be from the typewriter keys, not the numeric keypad.

Comment: But if you don't have a numeric keypad then you do not have the "-" (minus) key strictly speaking... and C-x C-maj-<the key with the '-' > does not work .. how then do it ? And the same problem for '+' since no dedicated '+' key !

Answer (score 8):

The -very nice- answer of user173973 is binding the functions to non-generic mouse events.  That is to say that for example on my windows system, the binding command is not valid.

To use it on windows (or probably anywhere) you can use these generic bindings :

```lisp
(global-set-key [C-mouse-wheel-up-event]  'text-scale-increase)
(global-set-key  [C-mouse-wheel-down-event] 'text-scale-decrease)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, even with `(setq w32-pass-extra-mouse-buttons-to-system t)`. Any ideas? (I'm on Windows 7.)

Comment: I've got it now, from Xah Lee's blog, I have success with `(kbd "<C-wheel-up>")`. Especially, describe key with `C-h k ctrl+scroll-up`.

Comment: For me (on unix) this doesn't work. Only the answer of @sawa works.

Answer (score 1):

This config worked for me:

```
(global-set-key [C-wheel-up] 'text-scale-increase)
(global-set-key [C-wheel-down] 'text-scale-decrease)
```

Comment: The [C-wheel-up] event also worked for me. However, I found [C-S-wheel-up] more prudent as it's not already assigned by default.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [sawa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/314166/sawa)'s accepted response, I prefer to use the keyboard exclusively. Here are some additions to my `init.el` file that meet that preference similarly to the short cuts found on Windows/MacOS desktops:

```
;; enable shortcuts (both keyboard and mouse) for zoom-in/zoom-out
(global-set-key [C-mouse-4] 'text-scale-increase)
(global-set-key [C-mouse-5] 'text-scale-decrease)
(global-set-key [?\C-\+] 'text-scale-increase)
(global-set-key [?\C-\-] 'text-scale-decrease)
```

Answer (score 0):

### All windows

You'll often want to change your font size because you're showing something to others. Then you likely want all windows to zoom in (including mode-line). For this, [default-text-scale](https://github.com/purcell/default-text-scale) is great.

I bind it as such:

```
(key-seq-define-global "q-" 'default-text-scale-decrease)
(key-seq-define-global "q+" 'default-text-scale-increase)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-_") 'default-text-scale-decrease)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-+") 'default-text-scale-increase)
```

### Quick single window, and back

For a really quick heavy (16x) zoom-in, you can use: `C-u C-u C-x C-+`

For going to single-window mode, say for a org presentation: `C-x 1`

Then you can undo the single-window and return to whatever layout you had before with `winner-undo`: `C-c <left>`

### Whole desktop

Relatedly, for sharing over a video call, it might be easiest to just change (lower) your desktop resolution. On linux, I pop up `arandr` for this before starting a sharing session.