# Can Vim zoom in and zoom out?

Tags: vim

I found we can do that in Emacs:

*[emacs zoom in/zoom out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533110/emacs-zoom-in-zoom-out)*

What is the equivalent in Vim?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the methods detailed here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font_size_quickly to create keybindings to do this for you. (Though I'm surprised gvim doesn't support this out of the box, MacVim does with <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>)

Comment: but this one only works for gtk2 version of vim. not a generic version.

Comment: My MacVim 8.0 does it with bigger: `CMD` + `=` and smaller: `CMD` + `-`. You can see more under Edit > Font

Comment: How to set default size?

Answer (score 20):

[The font size of a a console-based vim is determined by the font size of the terminal](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font). So changing the vim font size can be achieved by [changing font size of the terminal](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com.au/2014/03/how-to-change-font-size-of-terminal.html) that vim is called from :

```
|Terminal emulators |     + font size      |- font size
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    xterm          |Shift + Keypad Plus(+)|Shift + Keypad Minus(-)
|                   |Or control + mouse right click to choose the 
|                   |desired font size.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|  GNOME terminal   |Control+Shift+Plus(+) |Control + Minus(-)
|                   |Do not use keypad.    |Do not use keypad.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Terminator       |Control+Shift+Plus(+) |Control+Minus(-) 
|                   |Do not use keypad.    |Do not use keypad.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Konsole        |Control+Mouse Wheel   |Control + Mouse Wheel 
|                   |Scroll Up, or         |Scroll Down, or
|                   |Control + Plus(+)     |Control + Minus(-)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    lilyterm       | Control + Plus(+)    |Control + Minus(-)     
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| xfce4-terminal    | Right Click/Preferences/Appearance. 
|                   |   No keyboard or mouse shortcut.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| lxterminal        | Edit/Preferences/Style. 
|                   |   No keyboard or mouse shortcut.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| mlterm            | Control + Right click to bring up settings. 
|                   |Encoding tab/Font Size. 
|                   |   No keyboard or mouse shortcut.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| kterm             | Control + Right click to bring up font size menu.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|rxvt-unicode(urxvt)|Issue printf command inside terminal window. 
|                   |Eg: printf '\33]50;%s\007' "xft:DejaVu Sans Mono-8"
|                   |running this command inside flying vim is not       
|                   |working. One has to quit vim and issue the commmand
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: As [noted on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/897838/260416), xfce4-terminal supports the same shortcuts as listed above for GNOME terminal and Terminator as of [this 2016 commit](https://git.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-terminal/commit/?id=77194638860b9ddfe14e11bcad3fa9b66f840d8f).

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Ctrl -" to zoom out and "Ctrl + Shift +" to zoom in.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing the `guifont++` plugin

https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=593

Its default binding are:

```
+ increases font size
- decreases font size
= restores  font size
```